# why the code doesn't alert Worky-worky?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function() {
  function someSetup(){
    var setup = 'done';
  }
  function actualWork() {
    alert('Worky-worky');
  }
  someSetup();
  return actualWork;
}();
```

why the above code doesn't alert Worky-worky?it shows undefined.thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you only return the function, not call it.

Perform `a();` after this code execution, this will call the function that's returned by anonymous self-executing function, thus `actualWork`.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to return a function that has no return type (actualWork()).

It doesn't do the alert() because you didn't call the function properly.

`actualWork()`

`return actualWork;` is actually returning a variable, but because you didn't assign anything to that variable you're getting undefined back.

should do the trick.

Comment: "but because you didn't assign anything to that variable you're getting undefined back." --- actually no. I'm sure OP executes the code in console - so `undefined` is related to the whole expression `var a = ...` which returns nothing, `undefined`. PS: and to be precise: "is actually returning a variable" --- it's actually returning a reference. You cannot "return a variable", but you can return a value instead.